# Run class method based on tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, tags, decorator

I wanted to run the below class functions based on tag name provided at run time

```
def tag(tag_name):
    def tags_decorator(func):
        func._tag = tag_name
        return func

    return tags_decorator


class ExampleClass:
    @tag('foo')
    def method_a(self):
        print(" method_a foo")

    @tag('bar')
    def method_b(self):
        print(" method_b bar")

    def method_c(self):
        print(" method_c")
```

Expectation:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ec = ExampleClass()
    ec.foo # it should run the method tagged with foo i.e. method_a and should
           # print " method_a foo"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a weird requirement but you can implement `__getattr__` to realize it:

```py
class ExampleClass:
    ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for tp in type(self).mro():
            for obj in vars(tp).values():
                if getattr(obj, '_tag', None) == name:
                    return obj(self)
        raise AttributeError(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, how about passing parameters to method_a(self, name) via tag?

Comment: You mean arguments are passed to the `tag` decorator and then down to the method? Can you provide an example?

Comment: yes, you got it right. Thanks

Comment: Yes, simply define `def tag(tag_name, *args, **kwargs)` and then store `args` and `kwargs` alongside the `_tag` attribute and then invoke the function as `obj(self, *obj._args, **obj._kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @a_guest that it seems like a messy code design, I managed to come up with what I think is a decent solution for actual decorators.

Create a Tag class that can be initialized with a string for the tag and can be called to return a decorator that will tag a function that it decorates with string used for `__init__`.

```
class Tag:
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag
    def __call__(self):
        def tag(function):
            function.tag = self.tag
            return function
        return tag
```

Now the weird part - class decorator that looks up all the methods marked with tag and adds the attribute to the class with name of a tag and value being the method.

```
def TaggedClass(cls):
    methods_to_add = []
    for method in cls.__dict__.values():
        if hasattr(method, "tag"):
            methods_to_add.append((method.tag, method))
    for tag, method in methods_to_add:
        setattr(cls, tag, method)
    return cls
```

The class that will use tags need to be marked with the class decorator and method has to be marked with call to method decorator.

```
@TaggedClass
class ExampleClass:
    @Tag("foo")()
    def a_method(self):
        print("foo-bar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ec = ExampleClass()
    ec.foo()
```

Comment: This is not working at all !!

Comment: It most certainly works on Python 3.10 (3.9 even)